# Relationship between pH and volume

Tags: experimental-chemistry, ph, concentration

I had prepared two different volume of solution: $\pu{500 mL}$ and $\pu{100 mL}$ with same concentration ($1\%$), but I obtain different $\mathrm{pH}$. Will volume affect $\mathrm{pH}$?

Comment: [Welcome to chemistry.SE!](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) If you have any questions about the policies of our community, please ‎visit [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help). Best of luck!

Comment: The volume will not affect the pH.
However, any change in the concentration will

Answer (score 2):

*If correctly prepared*, the pH should have been the same. Logically, consider if the pH would be different if measured in 5 separate 100 ml samples poured from the 500 ml preparation.

Why might the pH differ in your tests? Some possibilities:

- One container was not completely rinsed after cleaning and had some (often alkaline) detergent clinging to it.
- The preparation absorbs $\ce{CO2}$ from the air, so the layer on top is more acidic.
- Error in measurement.

Unless you have a [buffered system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_solution), pH may vary abruptly with a slight change in ingredients.

Answer (score 1):

No, $\mathrm{pH}$ is not volume-dependent as it's an [intensive property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensive_and_extensive_properties#Intensive_properties) derived from another intensive property (concentration):

$$\mathrm{pH} = -\log{[\ce{H+}]}$$

The reasons for the different $\mathrm{pH}$ might be different, among them there are the following:

1. Contaminated beaker;
2. Solution absorbs carbon dioxide from the air differently due to different surface area of the liquid exposed to air;
3. $\mathrm{pH}$-electrode is contaminated or/and improperly calibrated;
4. $\mathrm{pH}$ values were measured at different temperatures.